# Android widget button animation

Tags: android, android-widget

In Android I have a widget with a button:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/btnPlayPause"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:background="@drawable/ic_button_play"/>
```

I want to apply a very basic *animation* to it when the user presses it.

Simple animation means: scale a bit down, and come back to original size.

Is this somehow achievable?

Comment: Did you find the solution?  please share here.

Answer (score 0):

```
but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               but.animate().scaleY(2f).setDuration(200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {

                       but.animate().scaleY(1f);
                   }
               });
           }
       });
```

Comment: that is your button `but = findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);`

Comment: Have you tried this? `findViewById` is not available on Android Widgets.